# Unit testing whether an exception has been caught

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, task

I have a method that needs a try/catch around it. This is because the method is called from a `Task`. If an exception is thrown the thread will end. I could use `Task.ContinueWith` to handle errors and then fire up a new task if an error occurs but a try/catch will do the trick.

Anyhow, I know I need to put a try/catch in but how do I test that the exception is caught?

One way I can do it is raise an existing event which accepts a string parameter and then in the unit test, test that this string matches a string I expect. Not sure if that's good or not but wondered what the best way to handle this scenario is.

Comment: Do not catch. Or perhaps throw the exception.

Comment: If exception is not handled by your `Catch` block then your unit test will fail anyways throwing that particular exception but if it's catched/handled your test will pass. Not sure whether there any specific way around.

Comment: Assert the exception, then the test case will not fail.

Comment: @zenwalker I'm trying to cover my bases and not test for specific exceptions. Bad I know but you can't think of every exception.

Comment: If you do not know what all types of exceptions your code might throw, then your not completely unit testing yout production code thus lowering with your quality. Even FxCop do report if used general exceptions for the same sake. Please read Art of Unit Testing by Roy

Comment: @zenwalker I have read it but at the end of the day I could put in checks for ArgumentException, NullReference etc etc but there is always that edge case that you dont think of that needs to be handled

Comment: If your using a 3p library, then the author would have specified all possible exceptions, except stackoverflow or memorycorrupt or Win32Exception just like MSDN does. So check out the API doc. Other wise if its your code, then you can figure out 95% of exception cases. The rest are system exceptions like Stackoverflow, etc, which you can not test but to fix it.

Comment: @zenwalker Ok lets say I do put in a check for all possible exceptions. I still want to test that the exception is handled surely?

Comment: The thing here is, you can not test every exception. You want such exception to pop up and then you have to fix it. No use handling it and do noting with it right? As said, system exceptions are very rare to occur, no use if you swallow it. So all i can say is do 95% test coverage and you'r far from good. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9587/discussion-between-jon-and-zenwalker)

Comment: Do you really need to catch this exception in this place?
Remember: in Unit Tests, you should test every method separately.
If you're testing something that uses another method, you can mock this last method.
Exceptions, in tests, you can catch with ExpectedException attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are doing TDD, you should move small steps and focus on what your classes should do. Here is example. You want to print some reports. First (I suppose you are moving outside-in) you design class `Report` which should print itself via `Printer` (that's just for example). So you write test:

```
[Test]
public void ShouldPrintItself()
{
   Mock<IPrinter> printer = new Mock<IPrinter>();            
   Report report = new Report(printer.Object);
   report.Text = "foo";

   report.Print();
   printer.Verify(p => p.Print("foo"));
}
```

And you write some implementation for `report.Print` method. Also you are designing IPrinter interface now. Next you understand that printer sometimes could show exceptions (e.g. out of paper). This is your case btw. So, you rename `report.Print` method to something like `TryPrint`, change first test and create new one:

```
[Test]
public void ShouldPrint()
{
    Mock<IPrinter> printer = new Mock<IPrinter>();            
    Report report = new Report(printer.Object);
    report.Text = "foo";

    Assert.True(report.TryPrint());
    printer.Verify(p => p.Print("foo"));
}

[Test]
public void ShouldNotPrint()
{
    Mock<IPrinter> printer = new Mock<IPrinter>();
    printer.Setup(p => p.Print(It.IsAny<string>())).Throws<Exception>();
    Report report = new Report(printer.Object);
    report.Text = "foo";

    Assert.False(report.TryPrint());
}
```

And you return to `TryPrint` method. Now you add `try catch` block around call to printer and make your tests pass (same you should do in your application):

```
public bool TryPrint()
{
    try
    {
        _printer.Print(_text);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // of course, log exception
        return false;
    }           
}
```

When you done here, you can move to `Printer` creation. In your case it would be component tests. Good news - you already have `IPrinter` interface designed. So, you write tests and verify that in some cases exceptions will be thrown:

```
[Test]
public void ShouldThrowExceptionWhenNoPaperLeft()
{
    Printer printer = new Printer();
    printer.PagesCount = 0;

    Exception ex = Assert.Throws<Exception>(() => printer.Print("foo"));
    Assert.That(ex.Message, Is.EqualTo("Out of paper"));
}
```

And of course, you write your component implementation to pass this test. After that both your class with `try catch` block works as expected, and your component works as expected, raising exceptions when it should.

Answer (score 1):

That you add a try/catch means that you have desired behavior when the class being tested calls another that throws exception. The try/catch is the "how", test the behavior.

So, using mocking, throw an exception when the "other" service is called and test that your class does what is desired. Write the test first, this will make you think of why you want to put a try/catch in.

Comment: I am doing the tests first. I just know I need that try/catch in there. Just not sure how I confirm that its been caught. I could not put one in and then have a try/catch around the other class that creates the task but I think I'd still be in the same position

Answer (score 1):

You should test **what** your application is actually doing, not **how**. So just mock your task to throw an exception, and verify that new task is raised in such case.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've gone with but would be interested in people's opinions:

```
[Test]
public void DoSomething_NullParameterEntered_ShouldCatchException()
{
    var component = new Whatever();

    try
    {
        component.DoSomething(null);  //If a try/catch block exists it will not fall into the below catch
    }
    catch
    {
        Assert.Fail();
    }
}
```

Comment: If try/catch block does not exist, your test anyway will fail because exception was thrown. So, you simply write test for `DoSomething(null)` without try/catch. And you write tests which expect exceptions from your component for `DoSomething(not null)`. See my example below.